# How to check if a model instance is attached to related model instance in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have many to many relation for `roles` and `permissions` models. I have an action controller for attaching and detaching permissions from users. How to check if some permission is detached to some role?

controller:

```
class RolePermissionController extends Controller
{
    // POST /roles/1/permissions/2/sync
    // BODY {isAllowed: true} 
    // $role - instance of role model with id == 1
    // $permission - instance of permission model with id == 2
    // roles and permissions has many to many relationship
    public function synchronize(Request $request, Role $role, Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->authorize($permission);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'isAllowed' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);

        // I want to check here if the permission is attached to the role

        if ($request->input('isAllowed')) {
            $role->perms()->attach($permission);
        } else {
            $role->perms()->detach($permission);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$role->whereHas('perms', function($query) use($permission) { $query->where('perms.id', $permission->id); })->count();`

Alternatively, say if you already had the permissions loaded:

`$role->perms->contains(function($value) use($permission) { return $value->id == $permission->id; })`

Comment: Thank you! $role->perms->contains($permission); works for me

Answer (score 2):

I simply use the association method of the first model to gain access to a query builder for the join table, then ask for the count of the associated model's column. In your case, I think:

$role->perms()->where('permission_id', $permission->id)->count() > 0